# Xaml, C#, Data Binding Multiple Tables MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, xaml, binding

I have problem with binding data in xaml.

I'm taking data from server through WebService and REST Client (json).
And I want to create list of books but in one table i have info about book like title in other table i have info about author and one more table to bind other 2 together through "keys".

I wrote something like this and its working:

```
IEnumerable<book> query =
            from x in authorsList
            join y in bList on x.id_author equals y.id_author
            join z in booksList on y.isbn equals z.isbn

            select z;

        return query;
```

But I don't know how to get authors name from this query if it is possible... In case it isn't I have next function with query like:

```
IEnumerable<authors> query =
            from x in authorsList
            join y in bList on x.id_author equals y.id_author
            join z in booksList on y.isbn equals z.isbn

            select x;

        return query;
```

But then I need to set two Data Bindings in xaml file and I don't know how.

Please give me any advice how to combine 2 different tables in one list of elements.

Comment: You compose all your data into a single class, commonly called a view model.

Comment: so i need to create new class that will connect the data that i need, am I right?

Comment: Reading the question again, I'm not sure I understand your question. I suggest you use a view model with MVVM pattern regardless, but  it looks like you could just do the first query then call `AddRange()` on it with the result of the second one.

Comment: I need to get list of items that have "title" and "name_author" but thoes two are in 2 different tables of DB. I need to merge them in one item. Is it possible with AddRange() ? I didn't know this function.